# Creating pod and service for custom kafka connect image with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I had successfully created a custom kafka connector image containing confluent hub connectors.

I am trying to create pod and service to launch it in GCP with kubernetes.

How should I configure yaml file ? The next part of code I took from quick-start guide. This is what I've tried:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc"
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.6
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:1.7.1
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:1.7.1
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-oracle-cdc:1.5.0
RUN wget -O /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

Modifield part of confluent-platform.yaml

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  image:
    application: maxprimeaery/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest   #confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.0.1
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0-1
  configOverrides:
    server:
      - config.storage.replication.factor=1
      - offset.storage.replication.factor=1
      - status.storage.replication.factor=1
  podTemplate:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 512Mi
    probe:
      liveness:
        periodSeconds: 10
        failureThreshold: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 500
    podSecurityContext:
      fsGroup: 1000
      runAsUser: 1000
      runAsNonRoot: true
```

And that's the error I get in console for connect-0 pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  45m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned confluent/connect-0 to gke-my-kafka-cluster-default-pool-6ee97fb9-fh9w
  Normal   Pulling    45m                 kubelet            Pulling image "confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0-1"
  Normal   Pulled     45m                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0-1" in 17.447881861s
  Normal   Created    45m                 kubelet            Created container config-init-container
  Normal   Started    45m                 kubelet            Started container config-init-container
  Normal   Pulling    45m                 kubelet            Pulling image "maxprimeaery/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest"
  Normal   Pulled     44m                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "maxprimeaery/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest" in 23.387676944s
  Normal   Created    44m                 kubelet            Created container connect
  Normal   Started    44m                 kubelet            Started container connect
  Warning  Unhealthy  41m (x5 over 42m)   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Normal   Killing    41m                 kubelet            Container connect failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m (x111 over 43m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  BackOff    17s (x53 over 22m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Should I create separate pod and service for custom kafka connector or I have to configure the code above ?

**UPDATE** to my question

I've found out how to configure it in kubernetes adding this to connect pod

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.0.1
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0-1
  configOverrides:
    server:
      - config.storage.replication.factor=1
      - offset.storage.replication.factor=1
      - status.storage.replication.factor=1
 build:
    type: onDemand
    onDemand:
      plugins:
        locationType: confluentHub
        confluentHub:
          - name: kafka-connect-jdbc
            owner: confluentinc
            version: 10.2.6
          - name: kafka-connect-oracle-cdc
            owner: confluentinc
            version: 1.5.0
          - name: debezium-connector-mysql
            owner: debezium
            version: 1.7.1
          - name: debezium-connector-postgresql
            owner: debezium
            version: 1.7.1
      storageLimit: 4Gi
  podTemplate:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 1024Mi
    probe:
      liveness:
        periodSeconds: 180 #DONT CHANGE THIS
        failureThreshold: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 500
    podSecurityContext:
      fsGroup: 1000
      runAsUser: 1000
      runAsNonRoot: true
```

But I still can't add mysql-connector from Maven [repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar)

I tried also making new docker image but it doesn't work. Also I tried new part of code:

```
locationType: url #NOT WORKING. NO IDEA HOW TO CONFIGURE THAT
        url:
          - name: mysql-connector-java
            archivePath: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
            checksum: sha512sum #definitely wrong
```

Comment: The container appears to be dying. Can you `docker run ` it on its own? Can you get the actuality container logs rather than the pod events? Also, default connect image memory is 2g max, so you may need to increase the resource request

Comment: I find out some info in doumentation about it [link](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-configure-connect.html#co-download-connector). But I can't add mysql connector separately from other resource. Example:  locationType: confluentHub #works great
        confluentHub:
          - name: kafka-connect-jdbc
            owner: confluentinc
            version: 10.2.6

Comment: @OneCricketeer, answered and added info to my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Connect CRD, unfortunately. You may have to reach out to Confluent support or forums to ask if they allow custom images or how to download JAR files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some retries I found out that I just had to wait a little bit longer.

```
probe:
      liveness:
        periodSeconds: 180 #DONT CHANGE THIS
        failureThreshold: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 500
```

This part `periodSeconds: 180` will add more time to make the pod `Running` and I can just use my own image.

```
image:
    application: maxprimeaery/kafka-connect-jdbc:5.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0-1
```

And `build` part can be removed after those changes.